# flycheck-irony installation on emacs

Tags: emacs, flycheck

> This is GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version
>   3.24.8)  of 2019-09-29

```
flycheck-irony.el:38:1:Error: Symbol's function definition is void: rx-submatch-n
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of flycheck. This was fixed in: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/commit/9fcdff7ef1f7fdb9e49e9b4c71a6df1d4e5bd705

> Use rx-to-string instead of the internal rx-submatch-n, which is gone
>   in Emacs 27 and never was intended for public use.

Answer (score 0):

Commit 2fa33eb earlier today has re-added rx-submatch-n to Emacs 27.0.50, for backward compatibility.